# Clone GitHub repository using Python

Tags: python, beginner, shell, git

I want to backup my GitHub repositories since there is news about blocking GitHub in India. I wrote Python code to automate this and would like for it to be reviewed.

```
import os
import requests

API_TOKEN='xxxxx'
#from https://github.com/settings/applications

api_repo='https://api.github.com/user/repos'

url = '%s?access_token=%s' % \
(api_repo,API_TOKEN,)

r = requests.get(url).json()
git_urls = [repo['git_url'] for repo in r]
for i in git_urls:
  os.system("git clone "+i)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`requests` is third-party, so (per the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) there should be a blank line in the imports:

```
import os

import requests
```

---

`api_repo` is constant, so should be `API_REPO`. There should also be spaces around the `=` in assignments:

```
API_REPO = 'https://api.github.com/user/repos'
```

Explicit line continuation isn't very Pythonic, especially when the line is short enough anyway:

```
url = '%s?access_token=%s' % \
(api_repo,API_TOKEN,)
```

Also, there should be spaces after commas (and I wouldn't bother with the trailing one). This would be better written as:

```
url = '%s?access_token=%s' % (API_REPO, API_TOKEN)
```

---

`r` and `i` aren't very good variable names. I would use `req_json` and `git_url`.

---

You are mixing `%` string formatting with `+` concatenation. You should at least be consistent, and I would use the more modern `str.format`:

```
os.system("git clone {}".format(git_url))
```

You should also be consistent with string literal quotes. Per the style guide:

> In Python, single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings are the same. This PEP does not make a recommendation for this. Pick a rule and stick to it. When a string contains single or double quote characters, however, use the other one to avoid backslashes in the string. It improves readability.

---

In all, I would probably have written it as:

```
import os

import requests

API_TOKEN = "..."
API_URL = "https://api.github.com/user/repos"

url = "{}?access_token={}".format(API_URL, API_TOKEN)
req_json = requests.get(url).json()

for repo in req_json:
    os.system("git clone {}".format(repo["git_url"]))
```

Comment: There is a stray `access_token` parameter in `API_URL` which should be removed I think.

Comment: Where in the style guide does it talk about blank lines between imports? I just read over it but I seem to have missed that.

Comment: pylint pep8 doesn't find it, but I've been doing something similar; std imports [\n\n] lib imports [\n\n] proj imports

Comment: @DavidZ: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports Section "Imports", second bullet, second paragraph.

Comment: You forgot mixing quote styles. Even your example has a single-quoted string in one place.